# Request body is empty, while submitting a form using Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I am trying to create an angular application with mongodb as a backend database. I have created forms using Reactive Forms. However, whenever I submit the form to post the data into mongo, the body is coming as empty in the console.log. I am attaching my codes here. I have tried a lot, but, still the error is persisting. May please help.

This is my **app.js** file.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-angular", { useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to database!');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('connection failed!');
  });

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join("backend/images"))); // allows to access the /images static contents folder

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

const postsRoutes = require('./routes/posts');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
const dprRoutes = require('./routes/dprs');
const atlasRoutes = require('./routes/atlas');
const acqProjectRoutes = require('./routes/acqproject');

app.use("/api/posts", postsRoutes);
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/dprs", dprRoutes);
app.use("/api/atlas", atlasRoutes);
app.use("/api/apc", acqProjectRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

The error lies in the **acqProjectRoutes** route. All other routes are working fine.

Following is my **acqproject.js** routes file.

```
const express = require('express');
const AcqProjectController = require('../controllers/acqproject');
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/check-auth');
const router = express.Router();

router.post("", checkAuth,  AcqProjectController.createAcqProject);

module.exports = router;
```

The following is the **controller** and **model** file for the same, respectively.

```
const AcqProject = require('../models/acqproject');

exports.createAcqProject = (req, res, next) => {
  const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get("host");
  console.log(url);
  console.log(req.body);
  const acqProject = new AcqProject({
    area: req.body.area,
    contract: req.body.contract,
    vessel: req.body.vessel,
    contractor: req.body.contractor,
    start_date: new Date(req.body.start_date),
    end_date: new Date(req.body.end_date),
    mob_start_date: new Date(req.body.mob_start_date),
    mob_end_date: new Date(req.body.mob_end_date),
    volume: +req.body.volume,
    source_interval: +req.body.source_interval,
    sail_line_interval: +req.body.sail_line_interval,
    streamer_length: +req.body.streamer_length,
    receiver_interval: +req.body.receiver_interval,
    shot_point_interval: +req.body.shot_point_interval,
    source_array: +req.body.source_array,
    streamers: +req.body.streamers,
    record_length: +req.body.record_length,
    prime: +req.body.prime,
    infill_cap: +req.body.infill_cap,
    prefix: req.body.prefix,
    direction: JSON.parse(req.body.direction),
    streamer_profile: JSON.parse(req.body.streamer_profile),
    planned_completion_days: +req.body.planned_completion_days,
    creator: req.userData.userId
  });
  acqProject.save().then(createdAcqProject => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'AcqProject added successfully.',
      acqProject: {
        ...createdAcqProject,
        id: createdAcqProject._id
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: 'AcqProject creation failed.'
    });
  });
}
```

The model for the collection is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const acqProjectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  area: { type: String },
  contract: { type: String },
  vessel: { type: String },
  contractor: { type: String },
  start_date: { type: Date },
  end_date: { type: Date },
  mob_start_date: { type: Date },
  mob_end_date: { type: Date },
  volume: { type: Number },
  source_interval: { type: Number },
  sail_line_interval: { type: Number },
  streamer_length: { type: Number },
  receiver_interval: { type: Number },
  shot_point_interval: { type: Number },
  source_array: { type: Number },
  streamers: { type: Number },
  record_length: { type: Number },
  prime: { type: Number },
  infill_cap: { type: Number },
  prefix: { type: String },
  direction: { x: { type: Number }, y: { type: Number } },
  streamer_profile: { type : Array , "default" : [] },
  planned_completion_days: { type: Number },
  creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('AcqProject', acqProjectSchema);
```

The follwing the is function in my service file, which is supposed to add a AcqProject into the database. I have checked multiple times, the data is logging fine.

```
addAcqProject(area: string, contract: string, vessel: string, contractor: string, start_date: Date, end_date: Date, mob_start_date: Date, mob_end_date: Date, volume: number, source_interval: number, sail_line_interval: number, streamer_length: number, receiver_interval: number, shot_point_interval: number, source_array: number, streamers: number, record_length: number, prime: number, infill_cap: number, prefix: string, direction: { x: number, y: number }, streamer_profile: [string], planned_completion_days: number) {
    const acqProjectData = new FormData();
    acqProjectData.append("area", area);
    acqProjectData.append("contract", contract);
    acqProjectData.append("vessel", vessel);
    acqProjectData.append("contractor", contractor);
    acqProjectData.append("start_date", start_date.toISOString());
    acqProjectData.append("end_date", end_date.toISOString());
    acqProjectData.append("mob_start_date", mob_start_date.toISOString());
    acqProjectData.append("mob_end_date", mob_end_date.toISOString());
    acqProjectData.append("volume", volume.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("source_interval", source_interval.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("sail_line_interval", sail_line_interval.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("streamer_length", streamer_length.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("receiver_interval", receiver_interval.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("shot_point_interval", shot_point_interval.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("source_array", source_array.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("streamers", streamers.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("record_length", record_length.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("prime", prime.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("infill_cap", infill_cap.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("prefix", prefix.toString());
    acqProjectData.append("direction", JSON.stringify(direction));
    acqProjectData.append("streamer_profile", JSON.stringify(streamer_profile));
    acqProjectData.append("planned_completion_days", planned_completion_days.toString());
 
    this.http
      .post<{ message: string; acqProject: AcqProject }>(
        BACKEND_URL,
        acqProjectData
      )
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      });
  }
```

The following is the console log of the server, I am monitoring using nodemon. I am confused why the body is coming to be empty as **{}** (just after logging the url).

```
> mean-course@0.0.0 start:server /home/bhanu/mean-course
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Connected to database!
http://localhost:3000
{}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at exports.createAcqProject (/home/bhanu/mean-course/backend/controllers/acqproject.js:28:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at module.exports (/home/bhanu/mean-course/backend/middleware/check-auth.js:8:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/bhanu/mean-course/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
```

May please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So to me it seems that `direction` or `streamer_profile` is undefined, because that unexpected "u" at position 0 is the first letter of the string "undefined". So I would suggest checking these variables for validity.

But why don't you just pass the whole object to your backend in JSON format? I think that would make things way easier.

Comment: checked it too. Both these variables are logging fine.

Comment: According to the error log the error occurs in controllers/acqproject.js:28:2, you already took a look on these variables in that specific location?

Comment: In the function addAcqProject() of my service file, I console logged all the vars before and after appending to the FormData Array (acqProjectData). They are logging just fine. It is in this function I am calling the post method of the backend. And there, I get the req.body as empty. In the developer console of the browser too it shows a 500 (internal server error).

Comment: In controllers/acqproject.js, req.body is empty. How can I check the values there?

Comment: I guess that's the cause of the problem, can you publish your server log?

Comment: In network tab of the developer tools, the request shows the body with the values. Which server log u meant ?

Comment: I mean the node.js server that is running in the background, have a look at it. When it returns 500 then it will output an error message that will tell us more about the problem, because the problem definitely is in the backend.

Comment: I have already pasted the server log in the question description. That's what I am getting. Maybe can try logging the whole request.

Comment: I found the solution, problem was that I was using body-parser to parse the data. However, body-parser has its limitations that it doesn't parse multipart/form-data. With using multer, I am able to get the body as required.